# Airflow: Get user logged in with ldap

Tags: python, flask-login, airflow

Does anyone know how I'll be able to get the current user from airflow? We have our backend enabled to `airflow/contrib/auth/backends/ldap_auth.py`and so users log in via that authentication and I want to know how to get the current user that clicks on something (a custom view we have as a plugin).

Comment: whoever -1 this, you should state why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by calling `{{ current_user.user.username }}` or `{{ current_user.user }}` in your html jenja template.

Comment: ```run_this = BashOperator(
        task_id='run_after_loop',
        bash_command='echo "{{ current_user.user }}"',
    )
```
produces the ```jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'current_user' is undefined```  error in Airflow 2.1