# Dynamic user impersonation in Airflow

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

Is there a simple, efficient mechanism to dynamically set the `run_as_user` parameter for an Airflow 2.0 task instance based upon the user that triggered the DAG execution?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563883/how-to-get-airflow-user-who-manually-trigger-a-dag) provides a way to determine the triggering user by inspecting the metadata database (earlier answers that involve templating--such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935428/airflow-get-user-logged-in-with-ldap)--no longer seem to work for Airflow 2.0).  Using the metadata inspection approach, I've been able to dynamically set `run_as_user` via a customer operator, like so:

```py
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.models.log import Log
from airflow.utils.db import create_session

class CustomPythonOperator(PythonOperator):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
 
        with create_session() as session:
            results = session.query(Log.owner)\
                .filter(
                    Log.dag_id==dag.dag_id,
                    Log.event=='trigger')\
                .order_by(Log.dttm.desc())\
                .all()
            
        self.run_as_user = results[0][0] if len(results) else 'airflow'
```

That said, this approach seems problematic for at least two reasons:

1. Ostensibly, it requires that the scheduler query the metadata database every time it instantiates the custom operator (rather than every time the task is executed).  The [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html) warns against expensive operations in the `__init__` method of a custom operator.  Moving the user lookup to the `execute` method of the custom operator does not work.
2. I suspect the semantics of this solution are not *quite* right: Specifically, I suspect that this approach will set `run_as_user` to the user that most recently triggered the DAG as of the most recent time that the scheduler parsed the DAG, rather than the user associated with the *current* DAG execution.  Depending on the scheduler interval, they may be the same user, but this would seem to introduce a race condition.

Is there a better way to solve this?